# Error: Access Denied in Claims Authentication, Custom Login Form

Tags: 2010, web-part, claims-based-auth

I created a web application Claims Authentication. I want create a custom login form.

I use this [link](http://mikevallotton.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/sharepoint-2010-claims-authentication-custom-login-form-part-1-modifying-your-config-files/) for create it. But when login it , I get error: **Access Denied**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does your login form inherit `UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase` ?  and need override the `AllowAnonymousAccess`
 property to return True, `AllowNullWeb` is a optional property to override to return true

Comment: I add a new Application Page in project Solution Explorer to create Custom Login page. I don't understand what you mean.!

Comment: e.g. your login page named CustomLogin.aspx.  when you open CustomLogin.aspx.cs, you will find  `public class CustomLogin:LayoutsPageBase`, change `LayoutsPageBase` to `UnsecureLayoutsPageBase`

Comment: Thanks, This use which reference?

Comment: the same of LayoutsPageBase

Comment: Thanks, I use this but i get error: Access Denied again :(

Comment: did you override the `AllowAnonymousAccess ` property and return true?